# Update column in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In the following table,i want to update the BreakTime based on comparing the difference betweeen the next record time and current record time.

[image]

I have tried this query:

```
update Machine_Data 
set BreakTime = (select DATEDIFF(SECOND, M2.Time, M1.Time) as BreakTime 
                 from Machine_Data M1 
                 join Machine_Data M2 on M1.DocEntry = M2.DocEntry + 1)
```

but it's throws an error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have row numbers in your table, you can self join during the `UPDATE` to line up the times appropriately.  Note that the join condition is that the current `DocEntry` should match to the one *ahead* of it in the joining table.

```
UPDATE t1
SET BreakTime = DATEDIFF(SECOND, t1.Time, COALESCE(t2.Time, t1.Time))
FROM Machine_Data t1
INNER JOIN Machine_Data t2
    ON t1.DocEntry = t2.DocEntry - 1
```

One other note is that the call to `COALESECE()` handles the edge case of the last record in the table (as sorted ascending by `DocEntry`).  In this case, it won't match to any record, so I choose to report zero for the break time in this case.

If your `BreakTime` column is `Time` type, then you could just use `DATEADD()` to set the time:

```
SET BreakTime = DATEADD(SECOND,
                        DATEDIFF(SECOND, t1.Time, COALESCE(t2.Time, t1.Time)),
                        '00:00:00')
```

Comment: Thank you Tim, is it possible to update the difference in time format like 00:00:02 (hh:mm:ss)..

Comment: @Vengat I updated my answer with what I think would work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
update Machine_Data
set BreakTime = (select MAX(DATEDIFF(SECOND,M2.Time,M1.Time)) as BreakTime
                 from Machine_Data M1 join Machine_Data M2 on M1.DocEntry =M2.DocEntry+1)
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.